ManagedChannelBuilder creates a ManagedChannel, but MyService.newStub only accepts an RpcChannel
I'm trying to use the following code to create a stub:
ManagedChannel channel = channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 41800)
    .usePlaintext()
    .build();
ObjectDetectionService.Stub stub = ObjectDetectionService.newStub(channel); // fails

However, ObjectDetectionService.newStub(channel); fails with the following error:
error: incompatible types: ManagedChannel cannot be converted to RpcChannel
            stub = ObjectDetectionService.newStub(channel);

Is this the correct way to create a stub from a channel? Is it possible to use a ManagedChannel as an RpcChannel?
Here's the full generated gRPC code:
package org.photonvision.vision;

/**
 * Protobuf service {@code org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionService}
 */
public  abstract class ObjectDetectionService
    implements com.google.protobuf.Service {
  protected ObjectDetectionService() {}

  public interface Interface {
    /**
     * <code>rpc ObjectDetection(.org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest) returns (.org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse);</code>
     */
    public abstract void objectDetection(
        com.google.protobuf.RpcController controller,
        org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest request,
        com.google.protobuf.RpcCallback<org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse> done);

  }

  public static com.google.protobuf.Service newReflectiveService(
      final Interface impl) {
    return new ObjectDetectionService() {
      @java.lang.Override
      public  void objectDetection(
          com.google.protobuf.RpcController controller,
          org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest request,
          com.google.protobuf.RpcCallback<org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse> done) {
        impl.objectDetection(controller, request, done);
      }

    };
  }

  public static com.google.protobuf.BlockingService
      newReflectiveBlockingService(final BlockingInterface impl) {
    return new com.google.protobuf.BlockingService() {
      public final com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.ServiceDescriptor
          getDescriptorForType() {
        return getDescriptor();
      }

      public final com.google.protobuf.Message callBlockingMethod(
          com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.MethodDescriptor method,
          com.google.protobuf.RpcController controller,
          com.google.protobuf.Message request)
          throws com.google.protobuf.ServiceException {
        if (method.getService() != getDescriptor()) {
          throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
            "Service.callBlockingMethod() given method descriptor for " +
            "wrong service type.");
        }
        switch(method.getIndex()) {
          case 0:
            return impl.objectDetection(controller, (org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest)request);
          default:
            throw new java.lang.AssertionError("Can't get here.");
        }
      }

      public final com.google.protobuf.Message
          getRequestPrototype(
          com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.MethodDescriptor method) {
        if (method.getService() != getDescriptor()) {
          throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
            "Service.getRequestPrototype() given method " +
            "descriptor for wrong service type.");
        }
        switch(method.getIndex()) {
          case 0:
            return org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest.getDefaultInstance();
          default:
            throw new java.lang.AssertionError("Can't get here.");
        }
      }

      public final com.google.protobuf.Message
          getResponsePrototype(
          com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.MethodDescriptor method) {
        if (method.getService() != getDescriptor()) {
          throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
            "Service.getResponsePrototype() given method " +
            "descriptor for wrong service type.");
        }
        switch(method.getIndex()) {
          case 0:
            return org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse.getDefaultInstance();
          default:
            throw new java.lang.AssertionError("Can't get here.");
        }
      }

    };
  }

  /**
   * <code>rpc ObjectDetection(.org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest) returns (.org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse);</code>
   */
  public abstract void objectDetection(
      com.google.protobuf.RpcController controller,
      org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest request,
      com.google.protobuf.RpcCallback<org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse> done);

  public static final
      com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.ServiceDescriptor
      getDescriptor() {
    return org.photonvision.vision.PhotonvisionRemotePipeline.getDescriptor().getServices().get(0);
  }
  public final com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.ServiceDescriptor
      getDescriptorForType() {
    return getDescriptor();
  }

  public final void callMethod(
      com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.MethodDescriptor method,
      com.google.protobuf.RpcController controller,
      com.google.protobuf.Message request,
      com.google.protobuf.RpcCallback<
        com.google.protobuf.Message> done) {
    if (method.getService() != getDescriptor()) {
      throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
        "Service.callMethod() given method descriptor for wrong " +
        "service type.");
    }
    switch(method.getIndex()) {
      case 0:
        this.objectDetection(controller, (org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest)request,
          com.google.protobuf.RpcUtil.<org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse>specializeCallback(
            done));
        return;
      default:
        throw new java.lang.AssertionError("Can't get here.");
    }
  }

  public final com.google.protobuf.Message
      getRequestPrototype(
      com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.MethodDescriptor method) {
    if (method.getService() != getDescriptor()) {
      throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
        "Service.getRequestPrototype() given method " +
        "descriptor for wrong service type.");
    }
    switch(method.getIndex()) {
      case 0:
        return org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest.getDefaultInstance();
      default:
        throw new java.lang.AssertionError("Can't get here.");
    }
  }

  public final com.google.protobuf.Message
      getResponsePrototype(
      com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.MethodDescriptor method) {
    if (method.getService() != getDescriptor()) {
      throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
        "Service.getResponsePrototype() given method " +
        "descriptor for wrong service type.");
    }
    switch(method.getIndex()) {
      case 0:
        return org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse.getDefaultInstance();
      default:
        throw new java.lang.AssertionError("Can't get here.");
    }
  }

  public static Stub newStub(
      com.google.protobuf.RpcChannel channel) {
    return new Stub(channel);
  }

  public static final class Stub extends org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionService implements Interface {
    private Stub(com.google.protobuf.RpcChannel channel) {
      this.channel = channel;
    }

    private final com.google.protobuf.RpcChannel channel;

    public com.google.protobuf.RpcChannel getChannel() {
      return channel;
    }

    public  void objectDetection(
        com.google.protobuf.RpcController controller,
        org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest request,
        com.google.protobuf.RpcCallback<org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse> done) {
      channel.callMethod(
        getDescriptor().getMethods().get(0),
        controller,
        request,
        org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse.getDefaultInstance(),
        com.google.protobuf.RpcUtil.generalizeCallback(
          done,
          org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse.class,
          org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse.getDefaultInstance()));
    }
  }

  public static BlockingInterface newBlockingStub(
      com.google.protobuf.BlockingRpcChannel channel) {
    return new BlockingStub(channel);
  }

  public interface BlockingInterface {
    public org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse objectDetection(
        com.google.protobuf.RpcController controller,
        org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest request)
        throws com.google.protobuf.ServiceException;
  }

  private static final class BlockingStub implements BlockingInterface {
    private BlockingStub(com.google.protobuf.BlockingRpcChannel channel) {
      this.channel = channel;
    }

    private final com.google.protobuf.BlockingRpcChannel channel;

    public org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse objectDetection(
        com.google.protobuf.RpcController controller,
        org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionRequest request)
        throws com.google.protobuf.ServiceException {
      return (org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse) channel.callBlockingMethod(
        getDescriptor().getMethods().get(0),
        controller,
        request,
        org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionResponse.getDefaultInstance());
    }

  }

  // @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:org.photonvision.vision.ObjectDetectionService)
}```
(Somewhat related issue - ObjectDetectionService.BlockingStub is private, even though ObjectDetectionService.Stub is public. Supposedly this is intentional, but it does prevent me from instantiating a BlockingStub. Even if it was public, BlockingStub has the same issue described above.)


That is not gRPC generated code. That is the old Protobuf RPC API, which Protobuf discourages.
You need to build the gRPC generated code using protoc-gen-grpc-java. The generated class name will be your service name with a "Grpc" suffix.
